# My MacBook Pro slows down

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

My MacBook Pro Specs:

- macOS Mojave 10.14.4 Beta (18E194d)
- Processor 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Graphics Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

When using Autocad, Excel, or Adobe (apps), my laptop slows down tremendously.

Is there any way to speed it up/find out what is slowing it down?

Comment: There is no way to tell what is wrong with the information you have given, can you provide more (such as apps running in the background, year of laptop, etc.)

Comment: The MBP that uses the [HD4000 graphics chipset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204349) is most likely the 2012 MacBook Pro.  It's probably a good idea to *not* run a beta version of an OS on a machine you depend on for work.

Comment: I agree with @Allan. You should install a more stable version of the OS and then share a screenshot of the processes hogging up your machine.